# Input Field does not exist

Tags: c#, asp.net, input

I have a control with input fields with id's and my .cs file says they do not exist. Here is the code for one of my inputs. Is there a reason that it does not exist?

```
 <input id="FirstNameInput" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name">
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ControlToValidate="FirstNameInput"
            Text="*" runat="server" />
```

Comment: This is a webforms concern, not MVC, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a runat="server" to the input or use

```
<asp:TextBox ID="FirstNameInput" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="First Name"/>
```

Comment: Wow I cannot believe I missed that.